# Function for testing hash table fails for apparently no reason

Tags: java, hashtable

This is an assignment that was given to create hash tables and various methods to interact with it, a class was also given to test it, after creating said hash table and methods and then running the test class an unexplained problem arose. One of the tests was to input strings and find them, using the implemented methods.

```
 Integer temp = new Integer(0);
 for (int k = 0; k < 200; ++k) {       // this function creates 200 unique strings and
     s = (new Integer(k)).toString();  // inserts them into the hash table
     h.insert("R"+s+"C"+s);
 }

boolean fail = false;
for (int k = 0; k < 200; ++k) {        // this function tries to find each string that
    s = (new Integer(k)).toString();   // was inserted into the hash table
    if (!h.find("R"+s+"C"+s) ) {
     fail = true;
    }
}
```

The function for finding the values inserted fails on each value, claiming it does not exist. Inserting and finding values outside of this function work perfectly fine, as well as working in other classes, leading me to believe that there is something about the function that the program is not agreeing with.

```
public boolean find(String key) {

    String stringKey = key;
    int hashToFind;

    StringHashCode sH = new StringHashCode(arraySize);

    hashToFind = sH.giveCode(stringKey);

    if ( HashTable[hashToFind] == stringKey) {    // this is where the method checks whether
                                                  // or not the place in the hash table matches
                                                  // the string we're trying to find

        System.out.println(stringKey + " was found in index " + hashToFind);
        return true;

    } else {

            return findDoubleHash(hashToFind, key);

    }
}
```

This is the find method used to find the inserted strings, it works in all other cases apart from the function given. It reaches the if statement and skips over to the findDoubleHash() method.
Debugging reveals that both the values, the string in the hash table and the string to find, are in fact the same and should be returning true. However this is not the case and a solution has not been found as to why.

As I've said, testing has revealed that this function is the only instance where the problem is present, any input or help would be much appreciated as to why this is the case.

Thank you

Comment: `(new Integer(k)).toString();` can be written as `Integer.tostring(k)`. It looks better, and avoids an allocation.

Comment: Is `==` the correct comparison operator here? Try  the  `.equals()` method.

Comment: changing `==` to `.equals()` makes the function give a NullPointerException, but allows it to work normally in any other instance. What could this mean?
Edit: Replacing these throughout the find and findDoubleHash methods has fixed our problem! :D
Do you have a bitcoin address? We would like to tip you.

Comment: Check whether the object is null before calling .equals() to avoid NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: Why don't you use `HashSet`, the standard implementation of a hash table?